# Why does a TypeScript array of objects filtered to remove optional properties still consider those properties to be optional afterwards?

Tags: typescript, filter

In the following case `namedThings` errors as it believes the type should be `(string | undefined)[]` but the `filter()` has removed any 'things' without `name` properties, so `t.name` will always be defined.

```
interface Thing {
  index: number;
  name?: string;
}

const things: Thing[] = [
  { index: 1 },
  { index: 2, name: 'two' },
];

const namedThings: string[] = things.filter(t => !!t.name).map(t => t.name)
```

Right?

TypeScript thinks not. What am I missing?

Comment: Why would TS think otherwise? It doesn't make a deep analysis of your code to figure out what the intent is. It only checks the types. `.filter()` preserves the type by default, because otherwise what do you think the result type should be for `things.filter(x => x.index > 0)`? The only thing that can be guaranteed type-wise for a filter is that `T[]` remains a `T[]` afterwards. Doesn't necessarily change to a `U[]`.

Comment: "*but the filter() has removed any 'things' without name properties*" it would *also* remove anything *with* a `name` property where the value is `""`. So, it's not exactly a straight check for anything *without* a property.

Comment: you need a predicate : https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAtQHNkG8BQyyoAJhAB4BcyIArgLYBG0A3ITXPRAPzUDOYKNjYBffPgQB7EAORhMILH2oZsAbQC6yALzI17XMRBkqyAIzIRAGgNGT1AExWOXagHIwAd0lvLNjWwS0rIgnBAkqorKyAJCipo6cgpKAHQwwAA2kFAAFDlgAJTUYMR8eHYU1HRMrC4Q-ILCljoAfMgAhO1gKaFcBSn0cAAO+a1yPWEFQA